# Crash on App launch because of insertion in Core Data ([NSManagedObjectContext insertObject:])

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-data

This crash is observed in some crash reports but didn't got it directly. I analysed lot of similar things on SO but unable to conclude on problem. Below are few images from the crash logs:

[image]

[image]

```
class CoreDataProvider: NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    static let sharedList: CoreDataProvider = CoreDataProvider()
    static let sharedDataManager: CoreDataManager = CoreDataManager()
    var isListObject: Bool = false

    var fetchedConversationResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>?

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        if let object = anObject as? NSManagedObject, type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.insert {
            if controller == fetchedConversationResultsController{
                CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.threadCoreBG.async { [weak self] in
                    **self?.fetchedConversationResultsController?.managedObjectContext.insert(object)**
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically crash is pointing out at highlighted line above.
where threadCoreBG is:

```
var threadCoreBG: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "coreDataThread", qos: .background)
```

I am doubtful that everything is optional then how it is inserting nil object if that's the case or I am unable to conclude whats the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectContext` instances manage their own `DispatchQueue` internally and you don't need to create your custom `DispatchQueue` to work with it.

```
let context = fetchedConversationResultsController?.managedObjectContext
context.perform { // This will use correct queue automatically
    context.insert(object)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `DispatchQueue` is not appropriate with Core Data. Inconsistent, difficult to reproduce crashes are exactly what happens when you use them.

With Core Data, you need to use `perform` or `performAndWait` any time you do anything that touches Core Data objects. `DispatchQueue` is a similar concept but incorrect in this case.

The only exception is if your code is running on the main queue **and** your managed object context uses main queue concurrency (for example with the `viewContext` from a persistent container). Then you can skip `perform` or `performAndWait` if you want.

You should:

1. Rewrite your `DispatchQueue` code so that it uses `perform` or `performAndWait`.
2. Turn on [Core Data concurrency debugging](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/) to help you find other cases where you need to make similar changes in your app.